# A counterexample of induction on integers?

Tags: real-analysis, induction

What could be an example of a property $P(n)$ pertaining to an integer $n$ such that $P(0)$ is true, and that $P(n)$ implies $P(n++)$ for all integers $n$, but that $P(n)$ is not true for all integers $n$?

(Reference: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/131ah.1.03w/week1.pdf, Page 33, The paragraph after lemma 18).

Comment: Let $P(n) = n > -2$.

Answer (score 3):

Any property that satisfy exactly the integers contained in some interval $[a,\infty)$, where $a\le 0$. For example:

- To have a real square root.
- To satisfy the inequality $x^3+100>0$.
- To be non-negative.

Etc.

Comment: Distinct from $-7$ is not an example, since $P(-8)$ doesn't imply $P(-8 + 1)$.